# Application icon not visible on device and exits

Tags: iphone

Getting the following error while trying to execute the application on device.

The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).

The application runs fine while connected with USB port, if i disconnect the USB from the device getting this error. Also the application icon is not visible on the device. If i search for the application, it is there on the device.

The changes done in sqlite is also not getting reflected in the application.

The application works fine on simulator

Comment: Try a clean and build, deleting and reinstalling on the device, rebooting the device, restarting Xcode... see if any of that helps.

Comment: I tried building,deleting and reinstalling... nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Unless the app requires communication via USB in normal operation don't bother about Xcode complains. A similar thing will happen if you an app is terminated by double tapping the home button and then "deleting" it from background.
- The file system on the device is case sensitive, the simulator is not. Check the spelling of your image name.
- And save your data before entering background, not only on appWillTerminate